# GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException: cURL error 28 when using Google Cloud Speech PHP API

Tags: guzzle, php-curl, google-cloud-speech

Following [Google's instructions](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/libraries#client-libraries-install-php) to the letter.

This is what I get:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException: cURL error 28: Connection timed out after 500 milliseconds (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) in C:\xampp\htdocs\ModernMT\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php:207 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\ModernMT\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php(162): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::createRejection(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle), Array) #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\ModernMT\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php(109): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finishError(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory)) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\ModernMT\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlHandler.php(45): GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory::finish(Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlHandler), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\EasyHandle), Object(GuzzleHttp\Handler\CurlFactory)) #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\ModernMT\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\Proxy.php(30): GuzzleH in C:\xampp\htdocs\ModernMT\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php on line 207
```

This happens right after:

```php
# Instantiates a client
$client = new SpeechClient();
```

Answer (score 1):

Straight from the developers of Google Cloud:

> After investigating a bit further, it looks like this is a bug in the google/auth dependency. We just merged a fix, and it should be tagged by the end of the day. You can wait for that (watch this page for v1.11.1), or you could require guzzlehttp/guzzle at ^6.5 to get it working right now. Sorry for the trouble, and thanks for bringing it to our attention!